# Could not find phantomjs

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, phantomjs

Getting the following error when trying to use phantomjs from ruby on Ubuntu:

```
 Failure/Error: visit root_path
 Cliver::Dependency::NotFound:
   Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path.
 # ./spec/features/search_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/vcr.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/vcr.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

phantomjs was built locally and added to PATH. How do I make ruby find phantomjs?

Answer (score 34):

You can also do

```
$ sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

That should automatically add phantomjs to your path, and do everything else necessary for it to run correctly. This worked for me.

Comment: The problem for me was that apt-get installs an older version (1.9.0) while I needed 2.0.0

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package phantomjs`

Answer (score 33):

Instead of building locally, use homebrew on your mac with `brew install phantomjs` and all the paths will link after. I had this error myself, and you'll get the links for free and have the ability to update easily.

Comment: As stated in the question, this is regarding phantomjs on Ubuntu, not Mac.

Comment: As google has proven, this is the top result for anything to do with phantomjs and that error. 3 upvotes also prove that you should fix the question as it's not OS specific.

Comment: You can't use just `brew install` anymore, it's now a cask, so do `brew cask install phantomjs`

Answer (score 16):

For `Mac Os El Capitan` use following command:

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```

Above command only works if you have installed `npm`, for installing `npm`:

```
 brew install npm
```

Answer (score 12):

add to Gemfile

```
gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
```

or put code below to spec_helper.rb

```
require 'phantomjs' 
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :phantomjs => Phantomjs.path)
end
```

https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The point of the phantomjs gem is so you don't have to install the executable manually. But without the executable installed by brew or apt, you have to point the driver to the bin path.

Comment: Agreed.  This should be the accepted answer.  This will save you a ton of headaches if you run your tests in a different CI environment.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the solution was to add phantomjs not only to the PATH, but also create links:

```
sudo ln -s /home/myuser/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /home/myuser/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /home/myuser/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
```

Adjust the `/home/myuser/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs` paths to match the path to phantomjs binary on your machine.

Answer (score -1):

Other possible solution is to add executable rights to file:

```
# download phantomjs
$ curl --output /home/user/.rvm/bin/phantomjs https://s3.amazonaws.com/circle-downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1
# set rights 
$ chmod +x /home/user/.rvm/bin/phantomjs
# check
$ which phantomjs
/home/user/.rvm/bin/phantomjs
```

And also it is not recommended by [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) to use `phantomjs` from official Ubuntu repos:

> DO NOT use phantomjs from the official Ubuntu repositories, since it
>   doesn't work well with poltergeist.