# phantomjs giving version mismatch

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, cucumber

Using

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Ruby 2.0.0
- (gem) cucumber (1.3.20)
- (gem) cucumber-rails (1.4.2)

Initially I had

```
Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path. (Cliver::Dependency::NotFound)
```

Which was fixed with https://stackoverflow.com/a/31333531/849697

And then

```
Could not find an executable 'phantomjs' that matched the requirements '>= 1.8.1', '< 3.0'. Found versions were {"/usr/bin/phantomjs"=>"127.0.0.1"}. (Cliver::Dependency::VersionMismatch)
```

Which bizarrely seems to be giving the ip address where ought to be a version.

`phantomjs` and `phantomjs --version` both give

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 127.0.0.1:10.0
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
[1]    1919 abort (core dumped)  phantomjs --version
```

*(there is no `--version` in the former)*

Comment: Strange. Have you tried to install PhantomJS from bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads

Comment: oo that fixed it! I can `--version` it now. And tests are passing. Put as answer? I'm not sure the correct way to install it, but I found the executable in the download and sudo mv'd it to /usr/bin/ overwriting the existing one, and checked chmod permissions

Comment: Feel free to add the answer yourself and all describe all the necessary steps you took to configure it in your environment.

Comment: I had to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496479/phantomjs-launcher-fails-on-latest-pop-os-cannot-find-shared-library-libprovid/72679175#72679175 to fix a related issue :)

Answer (score 0):

By installing phantomjs directly after downloading from bitbucket, `phantomjs --version` works, and tests are running and passing as expected.

https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads -> download, extract the phantomjs executable file, sudo mv it to overwrite `/usr/bin/phantomjs` which was installed through `sudo apt-get install phantomjs`

**edit:** previously I was doing this workaround:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum bundle exec cucumber
```

xvfb is a display server, to install `sudo apt-get install xvfb`