# Installing PhantomJS in R

Tags: r, phantomjs, rcrawler

I'm trying to install PhantomJS using the `webshot` package, SO I run the following on my machine:

```
webshot::install_phantomjs(force = TRUE)
```

At the end of the installation process I get the following:

```
phantomjs has been installed to /home/*******/bin
```

I go to that route and use the `ls` command to make sure phantomjs is there. When I type phantomjs on that directory I get the following:

```
Auto configuration failed
140184250763200:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
140184250763200:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
140184250763200:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=ssl_conf, path=ssl_conf
140184250763200:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=ssl_conf
```

Which is the same result I get when I type the following in R (`webdriver::run_phantomjs()`)

```
  phantom.js started, but cannot connect to it on port 4830. stdout + stderr:
>  Auto configuration failed
>  140690466219968:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
>  140690466219968:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
>  140690466219968:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=ssl_conf, path=ssl_conf
>  140690466219968:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=ssl_conf
```

My objective is to use phantomjs in conjunction with the RCrawler package, but this is a necessary step. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/Lima
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] webshot_0.5.5    Rcrawler_0.1.9-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] jsonlite_1.8.7    compiler_4.3.0    selectr_0.4-2     crayon_1.5.2     
 [5] promises_1.2.0.1  Rcpp_1.0.11       xml2_1.3.5        webshot2_0.1.0   
 [9] stringr_1.5.0     parallel_4.3.0    callr_3.7.3       later_1.3.1      
[13] png_0.1-8         fastmap_1.1.1     showimage_1.0.0   R6_2.5.1         
[17] curl_5.0.0        iterators_1.0.14  rlang_1.1.1       websocket_1.4.1  
[21] stringi_1.7.12    webdriver_1.0.6   doParallel_1.0.17 debugme_1.1.0    
[25] cli_3.6.1         withr_2.5.0       magrittr_2.0.3    ps_1.7.5         
[29] foreach_1.5.2     processx_3.8.2    rstudioapi_0.14   base64enc_0.1-3  
[33] lifecycle_1.0.3   chromote_0.1.1    glue_1.6.2        data.table_1.14.8
[37] codetools_0.2-18  httr_1.4.6        tools_4.3.0
```

Comment: It's probably related to a OpenSSL version mismatch, binaries you are installing were built with 1.1 while your 22.04 system is using 3.0. 
Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496479/phantomjs-launcher-fails-on-latest-pop-os-cannot-find-shared-library-libprovid , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355217/genymotion-throws-libssl-conf-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-o , https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15449 .

Comment: The fact that you are using R does not make much difference for mentioned workarounds, though you should probably ask yourself if using a browser that was built ~ 6 years ago is such a good idea.

Comment: Yes.. thats what I thought. But the problem is that the RCrawler package uses that browser as a workaround for dynamically generated websites.

Comment: I'd evaluate `chromote` (or `RSelenium`) + `rvest`, depending on your task it might not be that much extra work.

Comment: I use RSelenium for my task at hand, but it is extremly slow (because the scraper needs to go deper for each link in a given propietary website which updates daily) thats why I thought RCrawler would come in handy. From the links you provided I was able to open phantomjs from the terminal using the following: `export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null; phantomjs` but havent been successful doing it from R :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a wrapper script for `phantomjs` executable:

- rename your current `~/bin/phantomjs` to `~/bin/phantomjs.bin`
- create a new shell script and save it as `~/bin/phantomjs`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null
exec ~/bin/phantomjs.bin "$@"
```

- make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/phantomjs`

RCrawler should now execute the wrapper and `phantomjs` should pick up  `OPENSSL_CONF`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked as expected.  For everyone seeing this, create a raw text file without the .sh at the end, just as he said! Thanks again!