# Ruby script can't find phantomjs only when run from cronjob (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ruby, cron, phantomjs, ubuntu-14.04, poltergeist

I am not sure why this is, but I have phantomjs installed on my server

```
$which phantomjs
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

and am running a script from crontab as:

```
0 */5 * * * /home/roy/.rbenv/shims/ruby /home/roy/SCRIPT/lib/SCRIPT.rb
```

if I just run the exact command from the command line, it will run.

But if it runs from the cronjob, I get:

```
/home/roy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:143:in 
`raise_not_found!': Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path. (Cliver::Dependency::NotFound)
```

I've already seen this in possible duplicate [Could not find phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703886/could-not-find-phantomjs), but even if installed, it still does not appear to be working from cron.

Is there any way to check where this might be going wrong? Just for background this has been working as is for about a month, but broke when I tried to update from phantomjs 2.0.0 to phantomjs 2.1.1.

Comment: It could be that you have a different PATH when you execute the script in the cron job. You could try `puts ENV["PATH"]` in the script and see if it's different. Or you could pass a custom path when invoking the script in the crob job. `PATH=$PATH:/something/custom ruby thescript.rb`

Comment: since you're using ubuntu - you can set the environment variables you want available to cron jobs in /etc/environment -- heres a discussion about it - http://askubuntu.com/questions/700107/why-do-variables-set-in-my-etc-environment-show-up-in-my-cron-environment

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

When running executables `$PATH`, which is an array of directories, is searched for that executable.

For example if your `$PATH` contains `/bin` you can run `phantomjs` and `/bin` will be searched for `/bin/phantomjs`.

When running scripts from Cron, `$PATH` contains different directories than what it does when you run that script from `bash`.

### Solution

To run an executable without relying on `$PATH` simply use its absolute path. An absolute path starts with a `/`.

1. Run `which phantomjs` in `bash`. This will show `phantomjs`'s absolute path.
2. In your script replace `phantomjs` with its absolute path.

Comment: You're right, I suppose I could do that, but am wondering if there is a way not to have to put it in the script since that is how it has been prior (thought not sure why it just worked then and not now).

Comment: @roy There is. You can call your script like this `bash -l -c '/path/to/script'`.

Comment: Or you can set the path in the crontab like someone else suggested